# Error with simple rollover colour transition please help

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

trying to do a simple rollover colour transition in Actionscript 3, and I'm getting

> ```
> ReferenceError: Error #1069: Property transform not found on
> ```
>
> fl.transitions.Tween and there is no default value.
>             at dell_fla::MainTimeline/tweenToFinal()
>             at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>             at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>             at fl.transitions::Tween/setPosition()
>             at fl.transitions::Tween/update()
>             at fl.transitions::Tween/set time()
>             at fl.transitions::Tween/nextFrame()
>             at fl.transitions::Tween/onEnterFrame()

Heres my script

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
    import fl.transitions.TweenEvent;
    import fl.transitions.easing.Strong;
    import fl.motion.Color;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.geom.ColorTransform;
    import flash.display.DisplayObject;

    var startColor:uint=0xCCFF00;
    var finalColor:uint=0x003399;
    var colorInfo:ColorTransform;
    // Colour transition for country mouseover
    function initColorTransform(mc:MovieClip):void
    {
        colorInfo = mc.transform.colorTransform;
        var myTween:Tween=new Tween(mc,'alpha',Strong.easeOut,0,1,1,true);
        myTween.addEventListener(TweenEvent.MOTION_CHANGE,tweenToFinal);
    }
    function tweenToFinal(e:TweenEvent):void
    {
        colorInfo.color=Color.interpolateColor(startColor,finalColor,e.position);
        e.target.transform.colorTransform=colorInfo;
    }

    function countryMouseOver(e:Event):void{
        trace('countryMouseOver '+e.target);
        var countryMc = e.target;
        var localPos:Point = new Point(countryMc.x,countryMc.y);
        var globalPos:Point = countryMc.localToGlobal(localPos);
        trace('local pos: '+localPos+ ' global pos:'+globalPos);
        initColorTransform(countryMc);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [TweenEvent docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/fl/transitions/TweenEvent.html#propertySummary). The `e.target` is not your movie clip but the tween itself. Obtain your movieclip using `Tween(e.target).obj`.

```
   function tweenToFinal(e:TweenEvent):void
    {
        colorInfo.color=Color.interpolateColor(startColor,finalColor,e.position);
        MovieClip(Tween(e.target).obj).transform.colorTransform=colorInfo;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a million Jens! Its been a while since I've used Flash and AS3 is definitely a big jump from AS 1 and 2!